# Will instantiating a javascript function evaluate its member functions?

Tags: javascript, oop

Will instantiation of the below function cause an evaluation of `return _rows * _columns` in its member function?

So when I call `myTable.getCellCount()`, it doesn't repeat the evaluation, but simply returns the value? This can matter if instead of `_rows` being a integer, it was actually an expensive operation.

```
function Table (rows, columns) {
 // save parameter values to local variables
 var _rows = rows;
 var _columns = columns;

 // return the number of table cells
 this.getCellCount = function() { 
    return _rows * _columns; 
 };
}

var myTable = new Table(10,2);
```

Comment: `getCellCount` won't get executed until you call it.

Comment: You could add a `console.log(...)` call inside the function and see what happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instantiating `Table` will assign `getCellCount` method, but won't run it.

If it contains an expensive operation, you can cache the result:

```
function Table (rows, columns) {
 // save parameter values to local variables
 var _rows = rows,
     _columns = columns,
     _cellCount = _rows * _columns;

 // return the number of table cells
 this.getCellCount = function() { 
    return _cellCount; 
 };
}
```

Answer (score 1):

No. It will cause the execution of:

```
 this.getCellCount = function() { 
    return _rows * _columns; 
 };
```

That will not execute the function itself until you call it, say by executing `myTable.getCellCount()`.

Answer (score 1):

You can test this by putting:

```
console.log('called');
```

...inside your function.

You will see that it is not invoked in your code sample.

If you wish you eagerly compute the product and cache the value, you must do this locally within your constructor function.